# Predefined task return async many times

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I have a task defined at the top of my class like this:

```
Task<string> MainTask {get;set;}
```

And then inside of application I build this task.

```
MainTask = new Task<string>( () => 
{
    return Task.Run<string>( async () => 
    {
        await GetResult();

    }).Result;
});
```

I want to make a loop until the task returns data but once the task finishes first time I cannot start it again.

```
bool gotResult = false;
While(gotResult == false)
{
  MainTask.Start();
  MainTask.Wait();
  if(MainTask.Result)
  {
    gotResult = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: This code is very strange. Can you explain why you are not simply doing an `await GetResult();` in the loop? Why are you doing this business of wrapping a lambda in a task that that is itself wrapped in a lambda in a task?  This seems like a lot of unnecessary and dangerously wrong indirection.

Comment: Why are you using your `Task` as a field of your class and not awaiting and asyncing your `async` method?

Comment: hm...Shouldn't you await GetResultAsync() ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MainTask` shouldn't be a `Task`, it should be a `Func<Task>` (or, in this case, since the asynchronous operation appears to provide a boolean, a `Func<Task<bool>>`, allowing you to start the asynchronous operation any time you want by simply invoking the method.

So define it as:

```
Func<Task<bool>> AsyncOperation {get;set;}
```

Use it as:

```
while(!await AsyncOperation())
{
    //do nothing
}
```

As for assigning it, you simply need to assign the asynchronous method you have:

```
AsyncOperation = GetResult;
```

Note that you really shouldn't use the `Task` constructor every really.  Don't deal with unstarted tasks, it only causes confusion.  There's also no need to use `Task.Run` to call an asynchronous method.  It's *already asynchronous*.  There's also no need to use an async lambda to call an asynchronous method, both of those things are just adding overhead and adding no value.